# Could use help determining source of 500 (Internal Server Error) here

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My method for handling the request is

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitNew ( SolutionSubmission SS )
    {
        // Going to move this to model later .. 
        using ( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalJsPracticeDb"].ConnectionString) )
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AddSolution", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@problem_id", SS.ProblemId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@solver", SS.Solver);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@solution_code", SS.SolutionCode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test_code", SS.TestCode);
            /*
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@problem_id", 1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@solver", "Jeff");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@solution_code", "<span>Hehe</span>");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test_code", "<p>Yo</p>"); */
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return Json(new { success = true }) ; // TEST
    }

    // Going to move this to model later ...
    public class SolutionSubmission
    {
        public int ProblemId { get; set; }
        public string Solver { get; set; }
        public string SolutionCode { get; set; }
        public string TestCode { get; set; }
    }
```

and I call the request with

```
        $('#submit-solution').click(function () {
            var rowData = {
                ProblemId : $('input[name="problem_id"]').val(),
                Solver : $('input[name="solver"]').val(),
                SolutionCode: $('#solution').html(),
                TestCode : $('#testfuncs').html()
            };
            console.log(rowData); // TEST
            $.ajax({
                url: 'SubmitNew',
                method: 'POST',
                data: rowData,
                success: function (retobj) {
                    // ... 
                },
                error: function ( ) {
                    // ... 
                }

            })
        });
```

I've verified that `rowData` is valid in my test case: it is (stringified)

```
{"ProblemId":"1","Solver":"adas","SolutionCode":"\n\n        <div class=\"CodeMirror cm-s-default\"><div style=\"overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 3px; height: 0px; top: 4px; left: 4px;\"><textarea autocorrect=\"off\" autocapitalize=\"off\" spellcheck=\"false\" style=\"position: absolute; padding: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 1em; outline: none;\" tabindex=\"0\"></textarea></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-vscrollbar\" cm-not-content=\"true\"><div style=\"min-width: 1px; height: 0px;\"></div></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-hscrollbar\" cm-not-content=\"true\"><div style=\"height: 100%; min-height: 1px; width: 0px;\"></div></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-scrollbar-filler\" cm-not-content=\"true\"></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-gutter-filler\" cm-not-content=\"true\"></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-scroll\" tabindex=\"-1\"><div class=\"CodeMirror-sizer\" style=\"margin-left: 0px; margin-bottom: -23px; border-right-width: 7px; min-height: 48px; min-width: 253.208px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;\"><div style=\"position: relative; top: 0px;\"><div class=\"CodeMirror-lines\"><div style=\"position: relative; outline: none;\"><div class=\"CodeMirror-measure\"><span><span>​</span>x</span></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-measure\"></div><div style=\"position: relative; z-index: 1;\"></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-cursors\"><div class=\"CodeMirror-cursor\" style=\"left: 4px; top: 0px; height: 20px;\">&nbsp;</div></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-code\"><pre class=\" CodeMirror-line \"><span style=\"padding-right: 0.1px;\"><span class=\"cm-keyword\">function</span> <span class=\"cm-def\">myScript</span>(){<span class=\"cm-keyword\">return</span> <span class=\"cm-number\">100</span>;}</span></pre><pre class=\" CodeMirror-line \"><span style=\"padding-right: 0.1px;\"><span cm-text=\"\">​</span></span></pre></div></div></div></div></div><div style=\"position: absolute; height: 7px; width: 1px; top: 48px;\"></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-gutters\" style=\"display: none; height: 308px;\"></div></div></div>","TestCode":"\n\n        <div class=\"CodeMirror cm-s-default\"><div style=\"overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 3px; height: 0px; top: 4px; left: 4px;\"><textarea autocorrect=\"off\" autocapitalize=\"off\" spellcheck=\"false\" style=\"position: absolute; padding: 0px; width: 1000px; height: 1em; outline: none;\" tabindex=\"0\"></textarea></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-vscrollbar\" cm-not-content=\"true\"><div style=\"min-width: 1px; height: 0px;\"></div></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-hscrollbar\" cm-not-content=\"true\"><div style=\"height: 100%; min-height: 1px; width: 0px;\"></div></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-scrollbar-filler\" cm-not-content=\"true\"></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-gutter-filler\" cm-not-content=\"true\"></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-scroll\" tabindex=\"-1\"><div class=\"CodeMirror-sizer\" style=\"margin-left: 0px; margin-bottom: -23px; border-right-width: 7px; min-height: 48px; min-width: 253.208px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;\"><div style=\"position: relative; top: 0px;\"><div class=\"CodeMirror-lines\"><div style=\"position: relative; outline: none;\"><div class=\"CodeMirror-measure\"></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-measure\"></div><div style=\"position: relative; z-index: 1;\"></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-cursors\"><div class=\"CodeMirror-cursor\" style=\"left: 4px; top: 0px; height: 20px;\">&nbsp;</div></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-code\"><pre class=\" CodeMirror-line \"><span style=\"padding-right: 0.1px;\"><span class=\"cm-keyword\">function</span> <span class=\"cm-def\">myScript</span>(){<span class=\"cm-keyword\">return</span> <span class=\"cm-number\">100</span>;}</span></pre><pre class=\" CodeMirror-line \"><span style=\"padding-right: 0.1px;\"><span cm-text=\"\">​</span></span></pre></div></div></div></div></div><div style=\"position: absolute; height: 7px; width: 1px; top: 48px;\"></div><div class=\"CodeMirror-gutters\" style=\"display: none; height: 308px;\"></div></div></div>"}
```

For some reason, though, I'm getting a 500 (Internal Server Error). I get the same error when I substitute in

```
            /*
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@problem_id", SS.ProblemId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@solver", SS.Solver);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@solution_code", SS.SolutionCode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test_code", SS.TestCode);
            */
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@problem_id", 1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@solver", "Jeff");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@solution_code", "<span>Hehe</span>");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@test_code", "<p>Yo</p>");
```

Hence there there is some problem with my `SubmitNew` method that doesn't have to do with the body of the method. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you verified the connection string is correct outside of the code?

Comment: Why not to wrap in try catch and debug it?

Comment: Have you tried attaching a debugger or logging the exception?

Comment: 500 internal error is way to tell client that some exception occurred at server...As rightly mentioned by others, you should handle exception and log it.

Comment: if you don't have any proper error handling, and you are not swallowing the exception, check the server event viewer for uncaught exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Ok, guys. I fixed it by adding

```
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
```

to the JSON I was passing to the server.